# apache cache settings to get 200 or 304 as appropriate

Tags: ios, apache, google-chrome, etag, response-headers

I am running Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu (single server machine). I didn't make any changes to the default settings as far as cache headers are concerned (no cache-related change to /etc/apache2/apached2.conf, no .htaccess files). My understanding is that apache's default behavior is to use ETag's, with the desired behavior of returning a 304 if the client already has a matching file, or a 200 (plus the new file) if it does not.

This is not what I see.

On iOS/Safari, when I update files on the server, my client behaves as if it has a mix of old and new files. This can be resolved by clearing web data in Safari and reloading the page, so it does seem to be a caching issue. I read that iOS/Safari is (or at least was, in earlier versions?) different in its respect for ETag headers. But it wasn't clear to me how to fix this.

On Chrome in Windows, the file is always served (i.e., response 200, not 304) even when the file hasn't changed since the last request, even though I can see the use of ETag in the headers.

Can someone share their apache 2.4 settings to get the desired behavior I describe above, on both iOS and Chrome?

(Here is another question that asks the same thing about the Chrome part: [Apache + Etags -> returns 200 and send content instead of 304](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063580/apache-etags-returns-200-and-send-content-instead-of-304))

Comment: Please explain downvotes?

Comment: I guess people don't think that it's a useful question? I don't get why you're getting down-voted here... Maybe you should share your configuration settings so people can comment on what looks wrong?

Comment: @GuyKogus, thanks. I actually had a longer version of this question with a lot more details, but it got down-voted 3 times immediately (no comments). So I thought maybe they didn't like the length, so I submitted this shorter version, and it got down-voted 4 times immediately. Interestingly, it only had 2 views (including one from me) but it had those 4 down-votes. How is that possible? As for relevance of the question, I feel like I'm asking "how do you do the most common/basic/desirable form of caching on the most popular hosting platform?" :(

Comment: So that would be too general a question, really. SO is better suited for small, concrete questions like, "why does this algorithm not work?" There's a [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post that might guide you, but honestly you're not asking anything too broad here IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to my question is that caching works differently, at least in Chrome, when you are using the file:// protocol to test locally vs. the http:// protocol.